# Is there a way to use avatars from other user on the same playstation 4?

Tags: ps4, psn

I bought and avatar with another user in my playstation, is there a way to use that avatar with another profile in the same playstation?

Comment: Can you add more details to this question? What indicator are you seeing that you can't do this? In my experience any avatars stored on the system are available to all users to pick from. Although I don't have any "purchased" avatars, all of them were free or activated from within games.

Comment: Well, I bought and avatar of Metal Gear Solid with and account and when I try to look for it in the other one, I can´t find it. So, I´m not sure if that´s possible or I´m doing something wrong.

Comment: If it's not just there, then it's likely restricted by licensing. I have two accounts on my system and I've seen this with desktop themes, so it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use Avatars purchased on another account even though you are on the same console.

It's one of the few things that you can't use despite being on the same console as the purchasing user who has the same console as his "Primary PS4".

Other things which fall into this category include online passe. (even if you both have PSN but only one of you has purchased the online pass)